# Merging two series with alternating dates into one grouped Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

Given are two series, like this:

```
#period1
DATE
2020-06-22    310.62
2020-06-26    300.05
2020-09-23    322.64
2020-10-30    326.54

#period2
DATE
2020-06-23    312.05
2020-09-02    357.70
2020-10-12    352.43
2021-01-25    384.39
```

These two series are correlated to each other, i.e. they each mark either the beginning or the end of a date period. The first series marks the end of a period1 period, the second series marks the end of period2 period. The end of a period2 period is at the same time also the start of a period1 period, and vice versa.

I've been looking for a way to aggregate these periods as date *ranges*, but apparently this is not easily possible with Pandas dataframes. Suggestions extremely welcome.

In the easiest case, the output layout should reflect the end dates of periods, which period type it was, and the amount of change between start and stop of the period.

Explicit output:

```
DATE          CHG       PERIOD
2020-06-22    NaN       1
2020-06-23    1.43      2
2020-06-26    12.0      1
2020-09-02    57.65     2
2020-09-23    35.06     1       
2020-10-12    29.79     2
2020-10-30    25.89     1
2021-01-25    57.85     2
```

However, if there is any possibility of actually grouping by a date range consisting of start AND stop date, that would be much more favorable

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the explicit output?

Comment: I'd like for the output to have columns like this: DATE - Amount of change - Period 1/2 - where the last field reflects if it is the end of a period1 or period2 period

Comment: if it's possible to group by two dates in one row, that would be even better - then, output layout like START - STOP - CHANGE - PERIOD1/2

Comment: can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72704808/edit) the question with the exact expected output that matches your input? (make the input simpler if you want)

Comment: Will both dataframes always have the same number of rows?

Comment: @BeRT2me not necessarily - in that case, the (by time) oldest single row could be dropped or the change value left empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['2020-06-22', '2020-06-26', '2020-09-23', '2020-10-30'], 'val':[310.62, 300.05, 322.64, 326.54]})
p2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['2020-06-23', '2020-09-02', '2020-10-12', '2021-01-25'], 'val':[312.05, 357.7, 352.43, 384.39]})

p1['period'] = 1
p2['period'] = 2
df = p1.append(p2).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
df['CHG'] = abs(df['val'].diff(periods=1))
df.drop('val', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Date     period CHG
0   2020-06-22  1   NaN
1   2020-06-23  2   1.43
2   2020-06-26  1   12.00
3   2020-09-02  2   57.65
4   2020-09-23  1   35.06
5   2020-10-12  2   29.79
6   2020-10-30  1   25.89
7   2021-01-25  2   57.85
```

**EDIT**: **matching the format START - STOP - CHANGE - PERIOD**

Starting from the above data frame:

```
df['Start'] = df.Date.shift(periods=1)
df.rename(columns={'Date': 'Stop'}, inplace=True)
df = df1[['Start', 'Stop', 'CHG', 'period']]
df
```

Output:

```
    Start       Stop        CHG     period
0   NaN         2020-06-22  NaN     1
1   2020-06-22  2020-06-23  1.43    2
2   2020-06-23  2020-06-26  12.00   1
3   2020-06-26  2020-09-02  57.65   2
4   2020-09-02  2020-09-23  35.06   1
5   2020-09-23  2020-10-12  29.79   2
6   2020-10-12  2020-10-30  25.89   1
7   2020-10-30  2021-01-25  57.85   2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# If needed:
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.columns = ['start','stop']
df['CNG'] = df.bfill(axis=1)['start'].diff().abs()
df['PERIOD'] = 1
df.loc[df.stop.notna(), 'PERIOD'] = 2
df = df[['CNG', 'PERIOD']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              CNG  PERIOD
Date
2020-06-22    NaN       1
2020-06-23   1.43       2
2020-06-26  12.00       1
2020-09-02  57.65       2
2020-09-23  35.06       1
2020-10-12  29.79       2
2020-10-30  25.89       1
2021-01-25  57.85       2
2021-01-29  14.32       1
2021-02-12  22.57       2
2021-03-04  15.94       1
2021-05-07  45.42       2
2021-05-12  16.71       1
2021-09-02  47.78       2
2021-10-04  24.55       1
2021-11-18  41.09       2
2021-12-01  19.23       1
2021-12-10  20.24       2
2021-12-20  15.76       1
2022-01-03  22.73       2
2022-01-27  46.47       1
2022-02-09  26.30       2
2022-02-23  35.59       1
2022-03-02  15.94       2
2022-03-08  21.64       1
2022-03-29  45.30       2
2022-04-29  49.55       1
2022-05-04  17.06       2
2022-05-12  36.72       1
2022-05-17  15.98       2
2022-05-19  18.86       1
2022-06-02  27.93       2
2022-06-17  51.53       1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to compute the correct output in the project. 2020-06-23  53.81       2 -- 2020-06-26  10.57  1 -- 2020-09-02  45.65       2

Comment: Also modified the 2nd last line to this `df = df[['CNG', 'PERIOD']].sort_values(by="DATE")` to sort by date

Comment: Are your indices not in proper `DatetimeIndex` format?